# How should I initialise my stm32 ( f215 )

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m

I am trying to make an extremely minimal stm32f215 firmware to teach myself its boot-up intricacies. As it is now I have this dump which, to my knowledge, should write the stack address to r0 and loop forever:

```
firmware-d:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .isr_vector:

08000000 <vector>:
 8000000:       20002000        andcs   r2, r0, r0
 8000004:       08000009        stmdaeq r0, {r0, r3}

08000008 <reset_handler>:
 8000008:       f85f 00c       ldr.w   r0, [pc, #-12]  ; 8000000 <vector>

0800000c <loop>:
 800000c:       e7fe            b.n     800000c <loop>
```

But when I debug it I end up with PC = 0xFFFFFFFF, LR = 0x20002000, R0 = 0x0 and SP = 0x0.
And, also, nothing in the CFSR to hint at what goes wrong...

Any experienced coders here that have a clue?

(PS: the hardware boot pins are set to alias 0x0 to 0x800 0000)

Edit: I just realised that the CPSR has the overflow flag set. Still no clue why, though.

Edit2:

- All information I have found states that the cortex-m3 only can execute thumb and will hard fault if told to execute arm.
- I am aware that it is a bad idea to place my code in the isr_vector in the long term. I have tried padding it with addresses to "loop", but it made no change. I have this code as a minimal example.
- "With a breakpoint..." So far I have not been able to make it stop at any breakpoint. The only thing that works is "starti", which stops it before branching to "reset_handler". "stepi" from there puts me directly to the described state.
- This is a dump of the elf file, since it looks prettier than GDB's output. I have verified that this data exists both in 0x0 and 0x800 0000 on chip.
- Data from the card, fresh flash and "starti":

```
(gdb) info registers 
r0             0x0                 0
r1             0x0                 0
r2             0x6d8d1d05          1837964549
r3             0x7fbf              32703
r4             0x8000008           134217736
r5             0x8000008           134217736
r6             0x8000008           134217736
r7             0x8000008           134217736
r8             0x8000008           134217736
r9             0x8000008           134217736
r10            0x8000008           134217736
r11            0x8000008           134217736
r12            0x8000008           134217736
sp             0x8000008           0x8000008
lr             0x8000008           134217736
pc             0x8000008           0x8000008
cpsr           0x8000008           134217736
(gdb) disassemble /r 0x0,0x10
Dump of assembler code from 0x0 to 0x10:
   0x00000000:  00 20   movs    r0, #0
   0x00000002:  00 20   movs    r0, #0
   0x00000004:  09 00   movs    r1, r1
   0x00000006:  00 08   lsrs    r0, r0, #32
   0x00000008:  00 48   ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (0xc)
   0x0000000a:  fe e7   b.n 0xa
   0x0000000c:  68 46   mov r0, sp
```

(As you can see the value in 0xc is currently dead code.)

```
(gdb) disassemble /r 0x8000000,0x8000010
Dump of assembler code from 0x8000000 to 0x8000010:
   0x08000000 <vector+0>:   00 20   movs    r0, #0
   0x08000002 <vector+2>:   00 20   movs    r0, #0
   0x08000004 <vector+4>:   09 00   movs    r1, r1
   0x08000006 <vector+6>:   00 08   lsrs    r0, r0, #32
=> 0x08000008:  00 48   ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (0x800000c <reset_handler_c>)
   0x0800000a:  fe e7   b.n 0x800000a
   0x0800000c <reset_handler_c+0>:  68 46   mov r0, sp
```

- The board is a custom board based around the stm32f215. I use st-link (v2) to flash and debug through https://github.com/stlink-org/stlink.
  Flashing it with known good code works with this solution, but I am not sure if the debugger is working entirely as it should.
- Both boot pins are directly grounded through 1kOhm resistors.
- After changing the code a bit to branch directly to loop I can conclude that no matter what assembly instruction is first it will lock up. The branch back to loop caused the same error.
- The CFSR and HFSR:

```
(gdb) print/x *(uint32_t *) 0xE000ED28
$1 = 0x0
(gdb) print/x *(uint32_t *) 0xE000ED2C
$2 = 0x0
```

- I can very nearly guarantee that the stlink application I use is mixing up sp and lr. A known good program doesn't have sp=0x8f0d180 and lr=0x2001ff88. Will tomorrow look into using openocd instead.

Comment: Not familiar with the hardware here, but I know ARM.  If your ISR is landing on <vector>, then it is executing data and not code.  Almost 100% certain that those 2 op-codes are a stack address (0x20002000) and an entry point (0x08000009).  Note the address is odd, so the system assumes "Thumb" instructions.  Double check that this is what you want.  I'd assume ARM on bootup, so this is strange to me. http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka12544.html

Comment: Re-reading - the alias to boot to `0x800 0000` almost certainly means you are executing your "pool" and not starting at reset handler.  That also means you are probably throwing an exception on execution of the second instruction as R0 is almost certainly garbage.  Either make the first instruction a branch to your <reset_handler>, alias your boot pins to the <reset handler>, or move your pool away from the entry point.

Comment: "But when I debug it I end up ..." - but what did it do _before_ that? With a breakpoint at `reset_handler`, does it even stop there?  It is probably not a good idea in any event to place your code in the vector table; if an NMI or hard-fault exception  occur it will interpret your code as a vector and will jump to an invalid address.  Your `reset_handler` should be located above the vector table.

Comment: I would rather want to see that is in the FLASH not in the file.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan - Its a Cortex-M3 I assume due to the tag. Therefore it is always Thumb. The first entry in the vector table is the stack address. The next is a jump to the reset vector.

Comment: I am not sure if placing the reset vector code where the NMI vector should be is sensible or not. I don't think it will cause as issue.

Comment: @RealtimeRik It is not the issue unless there are some other hardware problem. But I want to see what is **actually** in the flash memory.

Comment: Another problem can be WDG

Comment: I dont see anything wrong yet, have to think more, the vector table is good its a cortex-m3 so it supports thumb2.  you have to have address ORRed with 1 for the vector to work.  what if you just mov r0,#5 or add r0,r0,#1 and do that in a loop so each time you stop and restart r0 keeps changing

Comment: add another 14 vectors and have them point at loop (orred with 1), and see if it is getting an exception

Comment: Is BOOT0 pin set to 0? I think what @MichaelDorgan said above might be correct. As old_timer said the code itself looks correct.

Comment: @P__J__ :  The code posted is a _disassembly_ not a source file, so it presumably _is_ what is in flash.

Comment: @Clifford no - it is disassembly of the elf file. What is in the FLASH only God knows.

Comment: what board are you using and how are you writing to the flash?

Comment: @P__J__ Good point. He mentions debugging it, so I assumed this was a debugger disassembly.

Comment: Show the disassembly generated by the debugger rather than a disassembly of the elf file to demonstrate that the code you are showing is the code you are running.

Comment: Fair point. Added gdb disassembled code. (I just find it harder to read the adresses in it).

Comment: Also answered the other questions, to be clear.

Comment: show HFSR, CFSR amd related registers

Comment: I know the HFSR and CFSR so have added those in full width. If there are any others I will need more detailed instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the culprit has been found!
It appears the st-util debugger (from the project mentioned above) causes an error somehow. openocd works like a charm and with that the minimal code above works.

Anyway, bug reports to write and all that...

**Thank you all so much for verifying my assembler and helping me with dotting all the t's and crossing all the i's!**